# how do i make a material ui autocomplete hide certain options when a certain option is chosen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am making an automod discord bot webpage and obviously part of those is where you select punishments to be made for certain offences. But not every combination of punishments makes sense(for example, there's no point having an offence cause someone to be muted and banned), so I want to make it so that if a certain punishment is selected, certain other punishments will disappear from the options.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea, You can try to set up that if some option is selected so some options will not display in renderOption for Autocomplete component.

Doc reference: [Material UI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31071155)